# Install Git Client on OS X without admin rights

Tags: macos, git

I need to run a git client on an OS X 10.6.6 machine to which I don't have admin rights.

Now unfortunately, the installer from http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/ has no option for a local install, so it just doesn't work without having an admin account.

What is the fastest / easiest way to install git, e.g. in `~/bin` ?

**Note**: While I can download zip archives from GitHub (from which my projects come), I need to be able to quickly pull new commits, so this is not an option.

Fink has no binary for OS X 10.6, and the MacPorts installer doesn't work either without admin rights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download Git source code and compile.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make
make install
```

Edit `.bashrc` or whatever to change `PATH`.

```
PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Dude, you are a hero! When I first read it I thought it wouldn't work, but luckily the machine *did* have developer tools installed. So this was a superfast action. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use homebrew to install git as a local user. That's a whole lot easier to update and gives you the chance to use the whole infrastructure to install even more goodies.

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Comment: Except you need git to update homebrew recipes, so you won't install git from homebrew without git :(